# Rails geokit caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, geokit

How would you cache GeoKit requests?

This does not work for me...

```
Geokit::Geocoders::query_cache         = true
Geokit::Geocoders::query_cache_max_age = 86400 # 1 day in seconds
```

URL: http://github.com/seebq/geokit-gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, so I'll just throw an answer out there:

Do you mean something like storing a hash of location/coordinates in memory, or in the database, for instance?

Comment: Geokit::Geocoders::query_cache         = true
Geokit::Geocoders::query_cache_max_age = 86400 # 1 day in seconds

this is not working for me... so I'm searching for an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure /tmp is writable from your server process.

> Note: /tmp must be writable in order
>   to use the query caching
>   functionality.

via [Seebq's geokit gem](https://github.com/seebq/geokit-gem). Make sure you are using Seebq's gem, because it is a fork of [Andre's geokit gem](https://github.com/andre/geokit-gem) to add cache support.